# Weird Behavior with some groups of keys interrupting if statements in C

Tags: c

The following program, written in C, should print "Pressed" while the Space bar is held. It does, however as soon as you press any of the following keys while holding Space: Shift, Ctr, Alt, Esc, Backspace, and possibly others that I haven't tested, the code in the if statement stops executing until you release and repress the space bar, even though the spacebar is still held and  GetAsyncKeyState(0x87) still evaluates to -32767 (pressed). (This also happens when you turn caps lock off while holding space, but not when turning it on).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

int main()
{
    int spacebar_pressed = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(1000);
        spacebar_pressed = (int)GetAsyncKeyState(0x20);

        if (spacebar_pressed == -32767) printf("Pressed\n");
    }
}
```

This also happens when the program tests if an F1-F12 key is held and another F1-F12 key is pressed, or when the program tests if an F13-F24 key is held and another of those keys is pressed.

It would be interesting to know why this happens, as I can't see any logical flaws in the program flow (although I am new to C), and I haven't seen anything like this in another language. I also couldn't see anything about this online, but maybe I just wasn't looking in the right places.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: To clarify, when I said that "GetAsyncKeyState(0x87) still evaluated to -32767 (pressed)" even when it wasn't printing "Pressed", I meant that the value of spacebar_pressed was actually -32767. I tried printing spacebar_pressed, and it was always -32767 as long as the space bar was physically pressed. This means that it was actually holding the correct value, even though the expression in the if statement wasn't evaluating to true. That is the weirdest part to me. I can't think of a reason that behavior like that would be possible.

Comment: [GetAsyncKeyState function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getasynckeystate) It looks like the intervening press of other keys will interrupt the continual reporting because there is no additional press of the space-bar afterwards for it to report `"whether the key was pressed after a previous call to GetAsyncKeyState"`. When no other key is pressed, it looks like it continues reporting key-down and there is nothing to interrupt the process. You will have to dig further in the docs -- that's just from a cursory look.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I thought something like that was going on at first as well, but I tried printing the variable that holds when the space bar is pressed, and it still registered as pressed ( -32767)  and that should cause the if statement expression to evaluate to true. I'll edit the original question to make that clearer.

Comment: What's weird there is reading the documentation the least significant bit is modified to determine the state, and the value of `-32767` is `SHORT_MIN + 1` (or `USHORT_MAX - 1` from an unsigned standpoint) So the return seems to indicate that is what is taking place and that corresponds to the documentation (though I don't use windows regularly, so I would have to look further to confirm)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks, I just looked over the return of GetAsyncKeyState and it turns out I just misread the output (somehow). It is -32768, not -32767, just as you said. Sorry for wasting your time. Thanks again.

Comment: Chuckling.... that won't be the last time that happens.... Welcome to programming...

Answer (score 0):

You're checking the least significant bit, which is what is causing your problem.

Just check if GetAsyncKeyState() returns true and this problem is solved:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
        {
            std::cout << "Pressed\n";
        }
    }
}
```